# how to have Phonegap InAppBrowser not cache the url content?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

am using this [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) plugin to load a url in a web view:

```
 window.open(encodeURI('http://app.website.com'), '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no,hidden=yes');
```

what happens is if i change the content of the url, when i restart the app, the content doesnt grab the latest changes, like is caching them or something

i tried using `clearcache=yes` and `clearsessioncache=yes`, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

if i set `target` to `_self` then the new content is shown

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple html cache content (a html content) you can put a random get param in the url:

```
http://www.example.com?param=4r287384hro23rh
```

If you can control the destination content you can avoid cache files if you apply Html5 cache control in a manifest file on . Files with no cache are in the NETWORK section

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="demo.appcache">
...
</html>
```

demo.appcache:

```
NETWORK:
Your.file
```

html5 cache doc: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp